# react-native-import/no-restricted-paths/ can not set a zone for the one target from a few folders

Tags: reactjs, react-native, plugins, eslint, eslintrc

Good day! Can you help me please with my situation. I have a folder structure:

```
my-project
 |----- node_modules.private
 |----- src
 │         |----- main
 |                    |----- api.1
 |                    |----- api.2
 |                    |----- components
 |                             |------ScreenLogin.js
```

In my project I have a hierarchical API structure. And I need to limit import of entities from ./node_modules.private and from ./src/main/api1 in ./src/main/components. That means I have to get the error in the case if import look like this if the current file being linted is ./src/main/components/ScreenLogin.js:

```
import { AccountService } from '../../../node-modules.private';
import { ChatService } from '../api.1';
```

And in my case the rule is set like this in .eslintrc.js:

```
  'rules': {
    'import/no-restricted-paths': [
      'error',
      {
        'zones': [
          { 'target': './src/main/components', 'from': './node_modules.private' },
          { 'target': './src/main/components', 'from': './src/main/api.1' },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
```

And interesting thing that the first zone is working and I get the error:

```
  27:37  error  Unexpected path "../../../node_modules.private/broker" imported in restricted zone  import/no-restricted-paths
```

But it is not possible to get the error from the second zone. Can you recommend me please how can I do it? I have tried many variants, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: probably .private on you node modules. why is that there? i never saw it

Comment: node_modules.private it is our company's creation, only in my project. Usually we put there some Api services. And It is possible only import a layer in api.1 from node_modules.private, and import a layer in api.2 from api.1, and afterwords to import some services in components folder only from the api.2, not from api.1 or node_modules.private.